# Let $R$ be a ring. Prove $I \oplus J \cong R \oplus IJ$ as $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

**Problem:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $I$ and $J$ be coprime ideals of $R$. Prove $I \oplus J \cong R \oplus IJ$ as $R$-modules.

**Attempt:** I know that $I + J = (1) = R$. I wanted to construct the map $$ \phi: I \oplus J \rightarrow R \oplus IJ : (x,y) \mapsto (x+y, xy). $$

I think it is easy to see it is injective. I wanted to show it is surjective. A general element in the codomain looks like $(r, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i)$ where $r \in R$, $x_i \in I$ and $y_i \in J$. Then I don't know how to prove that this element is actually in the image of $\phi$.

Help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is certainly not the map you want to use; it is not even linear.

Comment: Does "comprime" mean $I + J = R$ ? This is usually called "comaximal" (for better or for worse).

Comment: Hint: Fix $i \in I$ and $j \in J$ with $i + j = 1$ (these exist since $I + J = R$). Try the map $I \oplus J \to R \oplus IJ,\  \left(u, v\right) \mapsto \left(u+v, ju-iv\right)$. Do you see how to write its inverse? (That means solving a system of $2$ linear equations in $2$ variables.) This argument shows, more generally, that $IM \oplus JM \cong M \oplus IJM$ for any $R$-module $M$.

Comment: I'm not sure. I solved $u + v = x$ and $ju - i v = y$ and I got $u = ix + y$ and $v = jx - y$.

Comment: Looks good at a first glance. Just check that the two maps are mutually inverse by, well, computing their two compositions.

Answer (score 5):

Consider for any coprime left ideals $I, J ⊆ R$ the exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$0 → I∩J → I \oplus J → R → 0,$$
given by
$$I∩J → I \oplus J,~x ↦ (x,-x) \quad\text{and}\quad I \oplus J → R,~(x,y) ↦ x + y.$$
Note that $IJ ⊇ (I+J)(I∩J)$ in general (so $IJ = I∩J$ in this case) and that $R$ is a free $R$-module, making this sequence split.